# Call FormDialog from within a LUIS Dialog

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm stuck in my LUIS Dialog. I'm trying to call a FormDialog by

```
[LuisIntent("GetRestaurant")]
    public async Task GetRestaurant(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result) {
        try {
            FormDialog<AddressForm> addressForm = new FormDialog<AddressForm>(new AddressForm(), AddressForm.BuildAddressForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
            AddressForm address = new AddressForm();
            context.Call(addressForm, AddressFormCompleteAsync);
    }
```

After the call, my Emulator returns the first prompt (which city?) in my Form dialog, and takes the next input as Luis input and trys to match it against a LuisIntent.

My Form looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class AddressForm  {

    [Prompt(new string[] { "Which city?" })]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Prompt("Which street?")]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [Prompt("Which number?")]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public static IForm<AddressForm> BuildAddressForm() {
        IForm<AddressForm> addressFrom = new FormBuilder<AddressForm>()
            .Field(nameof(City), validate: ValidateCityInformation)
            .Field(nameof(Street))
            .Field(nameof(Number), validate: ValidateNumberInformation, active: NumberEnabled)
            .Build();
        return addressFrom;
    }
```

My Resume method does not do much yet, just for debugging.

```
private async Task AddressFormCompleteAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<AddressForm> result) {
        var adress = await result;
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
```

How do I stay in the FormDialog and do not jump back to my LuisDialog?
In case I need to use context.Forward(), does my AddressForm class then need to be of type IDialog and how do I handle the IAwaitable in the AddressFrom class?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now figured out an answer. It jumped out of the FormDialog because the prompt (presented in the Channel) counts as a Message Received for the calling method (where I called the LuisDialog), thus the FormDialog and the LuisDialog gets an context.Done. I had to be more careful with the conversation flow.

Comment: Hey, can you specify which changes you have made in above example to run properly?